# Is it possible to make widget return only data (eg, array)?

Tags: customization, widgets

I want to make widget to return only data (array variable).

Here is the code of my widget custom class:

```
class ContactInformationWidget extends WP_Widget {
  function ContactInformationWidget() {
      $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'contact-information');
      $this->WP_Widget('contact-information-widget', 'Contact info', $widget_ops);
  }

  function widget($args, $instance) {
      //echo $before_widget;
      echo $instance;
     //echo $after_widget;
  }

  function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
      $instance = $old_instance;
      $instance['adress'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['adress'] );
      $instance['phone_number'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['phone_number'] );
      $instance['email'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['email'] );
      $instance['site_url'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['site_url'] );
      $instance['column_name'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['column_name'] );
      
      return $instance;
  }

  function form($instance) {
  ?>
  <p>
      <strong><label for="<?= $this->get_field_id( 'column_name' ); ?>">Column name</label></strong>
      <input type="text" class="widefat <?= $this->id ?>" name="<?= $this->get_field_name( 'column_name' ); ?>" value="<?= (!empty($instance['column_name'])) ? $instance['column_name'] : ''; ?>" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" />
  </p>
  <hr>
  <p>
      <label for="<?= $this->get_field_id( 'adress' ); ?>">Adress</label>
      <input type="text" class="widefat <?= $this->id ?>" name="<?= $this->get_field_name( 'adress' ); ?>" value="<?= (!empty($instance['adress'])) ? $instance['adress'] : ''; ?>" style="margin-top:5px;" />
  </p>
  <p>
      <label for="<?= $this->get_field_id( 'phone_number' ); ?>">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" class="widefat <?= $this->id ?>" name="<?= $this->get_field_name( 'phone_number' ); ?>" value="<?= (!empty($instance['phone_number'])) ? $instance['phone_number'] : ''; ?>" style="margin-top:5px;" />
  </p>
  <p>
      <label for="<?= $this->get_field_id( 'email' ); ?>">Email</label>
      <input type="text" class="widefat <?= $this->id ?>" name="<?= $this->get_field_name( 'email' ); ?>" value="<?= (!empty($instance['email'])) ? $instance['email'] : ''; ?>" style="margin-top:5px;" />
  </p>
  <p>
      <label for="<?= $this->get_field_id( 'site_url' ); ?>">Site adress</label>
      <input type="text" class="widefat <?= $this->id ?>" name="<?= $this->get_field_name( 'site_url' ); ?>" value="<?= (!empty($instance['site_url'])) ? $instance['site_url'] : ''; ?>" style="margin-top:5px;" />
  </p>

  <?php
  }
}
```

I am trying to get the value of $instance array by outputing widget with `dynamic_sidebar(*sidebar_name*)`,

but the only thing I get is[image: output]

I also tried to `compact($instance)` in `function widget($args, $instance)` but `compact($instance)` but `extract()` at `index.php` (where I`am trying to output widget) makes error.

If I do this in `widget()` - it works fine:

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
  ?>
  <h4><?php echo $instance['column_name'] ?></h4>
  <ul class="fh5co-footer-links">
    <li><?php echo $instance['adress'] ?></li>
    <li><a href="tel:<?php echo $instance['phone_number'] ?>"><?php echo $instance['phone_number']  ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="mailto:<?php echo $instance['email'] ?>"><?php echo $instance['email'] ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $instance['site_url'] ?>"><?php echo $instance['site_url'] ?></a></li>
  </ul>


 <?php
}
```

But I want to make my widget to return only `$instance` array when I use `dynamic_sidebar()` .

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: This isn't possible and doesn't make a lot of sense, there's nothing to recieve that data. Widgets don't work like that. If you're trying to programmatically get the data for a widget in a sidebar, you should ask about that. That problem is solvable! It may even have been asked and answered on this site already. Why do you need that information? What problem does having it solve?